# Reading a creatures Melee attack

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I'm very new to Pathfinder and am trying to put pieces of information together. Thanks for your patience in advance.

I have a creature from an adventure path and his melee attack is listed as follows:

**Melee** dagger +3 (1d4+2/19–20)

Would be great if someone could help verify my below assumptions and clarify one confusion:

1) The creature is medium sized therefore I should assume that he would be wielding a medium sized dagger which is listed in the core rule book as having a DMG(M) of 1d4. This is where the **1d4** is derived from.

2) The creature has the following stats. Str 14, Dex 15, Con 15, Int 8, Wis 12, Cha 10. This implies that he gets +2 bonus to the attack roll, plus since he is a ranger, he gets +1 bonus more to the attack roll. This results in dagger **+3**.

3) The 19-20 is a special case dice roll threshold, where if hit, it would result in a standard x2 chance for a critical strike if the second roll exceeds his targets AC.

4) This is where I am confused: where is the +2 in the 1d4+2 coming from?

5) Could you give me a sample calculation with its damage output when the above creature has a successful attack roll?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> 4) This is where I am confused: where is the +2 in the 1d4+2 coming from?

The creature's Strength bonus applies to melee attacks; so his +2 bonus from his 14 Str is added here as well.

If the creature rolls damage, you roll a 1d4 and then add the 2 for total damage; so if you were to roll a 3 you'd deal a total of 3+2 = 5 damage.

Comment: Just might be worth adding - the OP's assumptions 1-3 are correct too.